# From Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012 (MVC 3 To MVC 4)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, web-config

Phase1 project is a webapplication developed in visual studio 2010 using Asp.net MVC3.
Now I want to continue my next phase with Asp.net MVC4 also shift the project in visualstudio 2012.
What are the changes I need to concentrate to make a smooth change,
This is my existing web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="AntiXssEncoder, Projname" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="ProjnameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Projname.csdl|res://*/Data.Projname.ssdl|res://*/Data.Projname.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLexpress;initial catalog=projname;user id=**;password=******;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check the official migration guide http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to migrate, but honestly, I feel that this is always going to be an error prone process, and if you don't know what it's doing and why, then you will probably run into problems.

My suggestion is to create a new MVC4 project, and simply copy all your source files over and re-add them to the project.

The reason I suggest this is that you understand your own project a lot better than you understand what MVC is doing internally, so you can likely fix any problems a lot faster in your code than a problem in the MVC code (because you didn't do the migration correctly).

I've done this a number of times, and it usually only takes a few minutes, while problems with a migration could take hours.